# Editing pages using Telescope Open Source Project

Tags: telescope

I just started playing around with the telescope open source project and I wanted to know how do you edit pages for example the signup page. If I wanted to add an picture to the background or something

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software tech support, and we are definitely not here to teach you how to use any particular piece of software.

Comment: That is a programming question, seeing that you would have to read code in order to do that.

Comment: then dig into the code and start working on it. like I said, we are not here to teach you how to use something. that's your job.

Answer (score 1):

Swifter, one issue with your question is that the documentation for Telescope outlines how to make small changes to the framework. To make an update like you are suggesting one would need to understand how a "view" loads styles. The documentation has a great walk-through on how to change styles or [theme Telescope](http://www.telescopeapp.org/docs/customizing/theming-telescope/).

A better question would be, I am coming from an HTML and CSS background. I noticed that Telescope uses SCSS. What is the Telescope/Meteor way to load a custom CSS library into the framework.

Answer (score 0):

one can also take this question to mean: "What is the correct way to alter telescope code?"

which would require you to understand meteor packages 
(see docs.meteor.com),

and the use of telescope-packages as the "telescope preferred way" to add your own functionality. You see, telescope is an app you base YOUR app upon, and telescope gets updated periodically and if you are using telescope as the basis for YOUR app, you should consider updating telescope periodically also, and the "package way" allows you to keep your custom code separate from the telescope code.

http://www.telescopeapp.org/docs/customizing/customization-basics/

http://www.telescopeapp.org/docs/customizing/creating-packages/